# How to deploy a JEE dynamic web project in a real hosting area?

Tags: java, web, web-hosting

I have developed a website using eclipse JEE and Apache Tomcat 7.0. I made the port forwarding and now I am able to log in from outside using IP address. I want to move this project to a real hosting area, like hostgator and godaddy, where i make sure the server will not go down. What I have to do ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look for Cloud JEE servers from some IAAS providers (aws, bluemix, openshift) to put code in your cloud servers.

Comment: How does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

To be more detailed - you will need to have a JEE server to deploy your code.
Just a domain name is not enough.

Look for IAAS provider which I mentioned or choose your best provider. Most of them provides App server as well as other components like database or other system integration components.

Once all setup - you will be able to create a rule to forward your domain to the application.

Hope this helps.